# Cannot drag boxes in calendar weekly column

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop

`UPDATED CODE BELOW:`
[image]

After doing a bit of workaround I can drag and drop boxes now however it drops at whatever timeslot is empty first rather dropping to actual timeslot `for example, if I drop box to 26th t1 to 27th t2 then it will drop the box to t1 27th instead rather t2 and now lets say I drop to 29th t6 it will drop to 29th t3 as t1 and t2 are full and t3 is empty so does not drop to right timeslot instead drops to whatever timeslot if first empty for that date` also once I load website again all the drag boxes I moved goes back to what it was before

updated code below

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { startOfWeek, endOfWeek, format, addDays, subDays, set } from "date-fns";
import "../assets/css/RunSheetPDF.css";

const DraggableBox = ({
day,
name: initialName,
suburb: initialSuburb,
calendarData,
setCalendarData,
changeName,
setChangeName,
changeSuburb,
setChangeSuburb,
setChangeDay,
setChangeData,
orderData,
setOrderData,
timeSlotIndex // Add the time slot index as a prop
}) => {
const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(false);
const boxRef = useRef(null);

const filteredOrders = orderData.order.filter((order) => {
  const orderDate = new Date(order.RequiredDateAndTime).getDate();
  return orderDate === parseInt(day);
  });
const handleDragStart = (e) => {
setShowTooltip(false);
setChangeData(filteredOrders[timeSlotIndex]);
boxRef.current.classList.add("dragging");
};

const handleDragEnd = () => {
boxRef.current.classList.remove("dragging");
};


const handleDragOver = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
};




  
console.log("Filtered Orders:", filteredOrders);

return (
<div
className="drag-box"
ref={boxRef}
draggable
onDragStart={handleDragStart}
onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
onDragOver={handleDragOver}
onMouseEnter={() => setShowTooltip(true)}
onMouseLeave={() => setShowTooltip(false)}
style={{
width: "70px",
height: "80px",
textAlign: "center",
backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5",
color: "#333333",
marginTop: "5px",
position: "relative",
cursor: "move", // Set cursor to move when hovering over the box
}}
data-day={day} // Set the day as a dataset attribute
data-name={initialName} // Set the name as a dataset attribute
>
<div style={{ margin: 0, lineHeight: "40px" }}>
{/* Render order details based on time slot index */}
{filteredOrders[timeSlotIndex] && (
<div key={timeSlotIndex}>
{/* Render DelCity */}
<p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{filteredOrders[timeSlotIndex].Id}</p>
{/* Render DelPostalCode */}
<p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{filteredOrders[timeSlotIndex].DelCity}</p>
</div>
)}
</div>
</div>
);
};




const RunSheetPreview = ({
orderData,  
setOrderData,
  selectedDate,

  initialName,
  initialSuburb,
  setShowTooltip,
  }) => {
  const boxRef = useRef(null);
  const [changeName, setChangeName] = useState("");
  const [changeDay, setChangeDay] = useState(null);
  const [changeData, setChangeData] = useState(null);
 
  const [changeSuburb, setChangeSuburb] = useState(null);
  const [selectedDateState, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
  
  const formatDate = (date) => {
  const dateVal = new Date(date);
  const year = dateVal.getFullYear();
  const month = String(dateVal.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
  const day = String(dateVal.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
};
const handleDragOver = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  };


   const handleDrop = (e, timeSlotIndex, dayOfMonth, year, month) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  // Parse the date and update the order data
  let d = { ...changeData };
  d = new Date(d.OrderDate);
  
  const number = e.target.tabIndex.toString();
  console.log("Number:", number);


    const currentYear = e.target.getAttribute('data-year');
  const currentMonth = e.target.getAttribute('data-month');
  console.log("Current Year:", currentYear);
  console.log("Current Month:", currentMonth);
  
  let day = Number(number);
  console.log("Day:", day);
  
  d.setDate(day);
  d.setMonth(currentMonth);
  d.setFullYear(currentYear);
  d = d.toISOString();
  
  let fi = { ...changeData };
  fi.OrderDate = d;
  fi.RequiredDateAndTime = d;
  
  let newDate = new Date(changeData.OrderDate);
  newDate = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, day, newDate.getHours(), newDate.getMinutes(), newDate.getSeconds());

  // Update the order data
   let newOrderData = orderData.order.filter(item => item !== changeData);

  // Update the order date for the dragged item to its new position
  changeData.OrderDate = newDate.toISOString();
  changeData.RequiredDateAndTime = newDate.toISOString();
  const timeSlot = `t${timeSlotIndex + 1}`;
  console.log("Time Slot:", timeSlot);

  // Push the updated dragged item to the new position
  newOrderData.push({ ...changeData, timeSlot });
 
  // Update the order data state
  //orderData.order = newOrderData; // Update the order data
   setCalendarData(newOrderData);
//   setChangeData(newOrderData[timeSlotIndex]);
  
console.log("Updated order data:", newOrderData);
};

// Remove the filter based on selectedDate
const dateStrings = orderData.order.map((listItem) => {
  const date = new Date(listItem.RequiredDateAndTime);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
  const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
});

const initialCalendarData = orderData.order.map((order, index) => {
  const name = order.DelCity;
  const suburb = order.DelPostalCode;
  return {
    day: dateStrings[index], // Use dateStrings array here
    name,
    suburb,
    initialName: name, // Assign the value to initialName
    initialSuburb: suburb, // Assign the value to initialSuburb
  };
});
const [calendarData, setCalendarData] = useState(initialCalendarData);




//console.log("Calendar Data:", calendarData);
//console.log("formatDate Data:", formatDate);
//console.log("filteredOrders Data:", filteredOrders);
//console.log("dateStrings Data:", dateStrings);
//console.log("Order Data:", orderData);
 


const generateCalendar = (timeSlotIndex ) => {
  const startDate = startOfWeek(selectedDate, { weekStartsOn: 0 });
  const endDate = endOfWeek(selectedDate, { weekStartsOn: 0 });

  const rows = [];
  let day = startDate;

  while (day <= endDate) {
const formattedDate = formatDate(day);
    const dateObject = new Date(formattedDate);
const year = dateObject.getFullYear(); // Extract year (e.g., 2024)
const month = dateObject.getMonth() + 1;    
    console.log("Month:", month);
    console.log("Year:", year);
    const dayName = format(day, "EEEE");
    const dayOfMonth = format(day, "d");
console.log("dayofmonth", dayOfMonth);
  
console.log("format date",formattedDate);
    const isTargetDate = dateStrings.includes(formattedDate);

    const ordersForDay = orderData.order.filter(order => {
      const orderDate = new Date(order.RequiredDateAndTime).getDate();
      return orderDate === parseInt(dayOfMonth);
    });
  
      // Find the first available time slot for the current day
      const firstAvailableSlot = ordersForDay.findIndex(order => !order.isAssigned);
  
      const row = (
        <tr key={day}>
          <td className="calendar-cell">
            <div className="day-name">{dayName}</div>
            <div className="day-number">{dayOfMonth}</div>
      
          </td>
          {[...Array(10)].map((_, index) => (
            <td key={index} className={`grid-cell`} data-has-data={ordersForDay[index] ? "true" : "false"} >
              {/* Render DraggableBox only if there is an order for this column */}
              {ordersForDay[index] && (
                <DraggableBox
                  day={parseInt(dayOfMonth)}
                  initialName={ordersForDay[index].DelCity}
                  initialSuburb={ordersForDay[index].DelPostalCode}
                  calendarData={calendarData}
                  setCalendarData={setCalendarData}
                  changeName={changeName}
                  setOrderData={setOrderData} // Pass the setOrderData function
                  setChangeName={setChangeName}
                  changeDay={changeDay}
                  setChangeDay={setChangeDay}
                  changeSuburb={changeSuburb}
                  setChangeSuburb={setChangeSuburb}
                  setChangeData={setChangeData}
                  orderData={orderData}
                  timeSlotIndex={index} 
                />
              )}
              {!ordersForDay[index] && (
                <p
                  style={{
                    height: "90px",
                    display: "flex",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                  }}
                  onDragOver={handleDragOver}
                 onDrop={(e) => handleDrop(e, index, parseInt(dayOfMonth), year, month)}

                  tabIndex={dayOfMonth}
                  data-year={year}
                  data-month={month}
                  ></p>
                  )}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          );
      
          rows.push(row);
      
          day = addDays(day, 1);
        }
      
        return rows;
      };
      
      
      
      const handleNextWeek = () => {
      setSelectedDate(addDays(selectedDate, 7));
      };
      const handlePreviousWeek = () => {
        setSelectedDate(subDays(selectedDate, 7));
};
return (
<div style={{ width: "100%", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center", marginTop: "20px" }}>
<div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", marginBottom: "0px" }}>
<h2 style={{ color: "#333333", margin: 0 }}>{format(startOfWeek(selectedDate), "MMMM d")} - {format(endOfWeek(selectedDate), "MMMM d, yyyy")}</h2>
</div>
<div className="calendar-container">
<table className="calendar-table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>{/* Empty header cell for labels */}</th>

{[...Array(10)].map((_, index) => (
<th key={index}>t{index + 1}</th>
))}

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{generateCalendar()}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
);
};

export default RunSheetPreview;
```

also the data I am using is just order no so it could be any such as 190, 182 etc and suburb name in the dragbox

Comment: const RunSheetPreview = ({ selectedDate, orderData }) 
what props are passed as selectedDate & orderData in this line  ( Can you provide dummy data ) ?

Comment: @SinghJatin the selected date is what you select on calender so for example if you select  7th of mach 2023 it will show 2023-03-08a and for the orderData has 0
: 
`{Id: 138, CustomerID: 162, OrderOf: 1, OrderDate: '2023-08-08T00:00:00.000Z}` this is one value but it has multiple of those in array

Comment: @SinghJatin have updated my question with being able to solve a bit of problem 3 I asked but still stuck if you could have a look at the problem 3 updated code please

Comment: @SinghJatin provided the original data as well please have a look

Comment: in the previous question that drag and drop i have shared a chat room link can you join that its difficult to discuss code issue here

Answer (score 0):

The code is as explained in the chat room.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { startOfWeek, endOfWeek, format, addDays, subDays } from "date-fns";
import "./RunSheetPDF.css";

const DraggableBox = ({
  day,
  initialName,
  initialSuburb,
  setChangeData,
  orderData,
  timeSlotIndex, // Add the time slot index as a prop
}) => {
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(false);
  const boxRef = useRef(null);

  const handleDragStart = (e) => {
    setShowTooltip(false);
    setChangeData(filteredOrders[timeSlotIndex]);
    boxRef.current.classList.add("dragging");
  };

  const handleDragEnd = () => {
    boxRef.current.classList.remove("dragging");
  };

  const filteredOrders = orderData.order.filter((order) => {
    const orderDate = new Date(order.RequiredDateAndTime).getDate();
    return orderDate === parseInt(day);
  });

  return (
    <div
      className="drag-box"
      ref={boxRef}
      draggable
      onDragStart={handleDragStart}
      onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
      onMouseEnter={() => setShowTooltip(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setShowTooltip(false)}
      style={{
        height: "80px",
        textAlign: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5",
        color: "#333333",
        marginTop: "5px",
        position: "relative",
        cursor: "move", // Set cursor to move when hovering over the box
      }}
      data-day={day} // Set the day as a dataset attribute
      data-name={initialName} // Set the name as a dataset attribute
    >
      <div style={{ margin: 0, lineHeight: "40px" }}>
        {filteredOrders[timeSlotIndex] && (
          <div key={timeSlotIndex}>
            <p style={{ margin: 0 }} className="el">
              {filteredOrders[timeSlotIndex].DelCity}
            </p>
            <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>
              {filteredOrders[timeSlotIndex].DelPostalCode}
            </p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      {showTooltip && (
        <div className="tooltip">
          <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{initialName}</p>
          <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{initialSuburb}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const RunSheetPreview = ({ selectedDate = "2023-08-27", orderData }) => {
  const boxRef = useRef(null);
  const [changeData, setChangeData] = useState(null);
  const [selectedDateState, setSelectedDateState] = useState(new Date());

  const formatDate = (date) => {
    const dateVal = new Date(date);
    const year = dateVal.getFullYear();
    const month = String(dateVal.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
    const day = String(dateVal.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  };

  const formatDate1 = (date) => {
    const dateVal = new Date(date);
    const year = dateVal.getFullYear();
    const month = String(dateVal.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
    const day = String(dateVal.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    return `${year}${month}${day}`;
  };

  const initialCalendarData = orderData.order.map((order) => ({
    day: 31, // Assuming day 31 is default for all orders, you can change this if needed
    date: order.RequiredDateAndTime,
    name: order.DelCity,
    suburb: order.DelPostalCode,
  }));

  // console.log(initialCalendarData);

  const [calendarData, setCalendarData] = useState(initialCalendarData);

  let filteredOrders = [];

  let startDate = startOfWeek(selectedDate, { weekStartsOn: 0 });
  const endDate = endOfWeek(selectedDate, { weekStartsOn: 0 });

  while (startDate <= endDate) {
    let fO = [];
    fO = orderData.order.filter(myF);
    startDate = addDays(startDate, 1);
  }
  function myF(order) {
    if (order.RequiredDateAndTime.substring(0, 10) === formatDate(startDate)) {
      filteredOrders.push(order);
    }
  }

  const dateStrings = filteredOrders.map((listItem, index) => {
    const date = new Date(listItem.RequiredDateAndTime);
    const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  });

  const dayStrings = filteredOrders.map((listItem, index) => {
    const date = new Date(listItem.RequiredDateAndTime);
    const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    return day;
  });

  // dayStrings.map((day) => {
  //   const parsedDay = parseInt(day);
  //   console.log("Parsed Day:", parsedDay); //returns 31
  // });

  // console.log("Calendar Data:", calendarData);
  // console.log("formatDate Data:", formatDate);
  // console.log("filteredOrders Data:", filteredOrders);
  // console.log("dayStrings Data:", dayStrings);
  // console.log("dateStrings Data:", dateStrings);
  // console.log("Order Data:", orderData);
  const generateCalendar = () => {
    const startDate = startOfWeek(selectedDate, { weekStartsOn: 0 });
    const endDate = endOfWeek(selectedDate, { weekStartsOn: 0 });

    const rows = [];
    let day = startDate;

    while (day <= endDate) {
      const cellDate = formatDate1(day);
      const dayName = format(day, "EEEE");
      const dayOfMonth = format(day, "d");

      const formattedDate = formatDate(day);

      const isTargetDate = dateStrings.includes(formattedDate);

      const ordersForDay = filteredOrders.filter((order) => {
        const orderDate = new Date(order.RequiredDateAndTime).getDate();
        return orderDate === parseInt(dayOfMonth);
      });

      // Find the first available time slot for the current day
      const firstAvailableSlot = ordersForDay.findIndex(
        (order) => !order.isAssigned
      );

      const handleDragOver = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      };

      const handleDrop = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        let d = { ...changeData };
        d = new Date(d.OrderDate);

        const number = e.target.tabIndex.toString();

        let year = Number(number.substring(0, 4));

        let month = number.substring(4).substring(0, 2);
        month =
          Number(month.substring(0, 1)) === 0
            ? Number(month.substring(1)) - 1
            : Number(month) - 1;

        let day = number.substring(6);
        day =
          Number(day.substring(0, 1)) === 0
            ? Number(day.substring(1))
            : Number(day);

        d.setDate(day);
        d.setMonth(month);
        d.setFullYear(year);
        d = d.toISOString();

        let fi = { ...changeData };
        fi.OrderDate = d;
        fi.RequiredDateAndTime = d;

        let newOrderData = orderData.order.filter(myFilter);
        function myFilter(item) {
          if (item === changeData) {
            return;
          }
          return item;
        }
        newOrderData.push(fi);
        // console.log(orderData.order);
        orderData.order = newOrderData;
        // console.log(orderData.order);
      };

      const row = (
        <tr key={day}>
          <td className="calendar-cell">
            <div className="day-name">{dayName}</div>
            <div className="day-number">{dayOfMonth}</div>
          </td>
          {[...Array(10)].map((_, index) => (
            <td
              key={index}
              className={`grid-cell`}
              data-has-data={ordersForDay[index] ? "true" : "false"}
            >
              {/* Render DraggableBox only if there is an order for this column */}
              {ordersForDay[index] ? (
                <DraggableBox
                  day={parseInt(dayOfMonth)}
                  initialName={ordersForDay[index].DelCity}
                  initialSuburb={ordersForDay[index].DelPostalCode}
                  setChangeData={setChangeData}
                  orderData={orderData}
                  timeSlotIndex={index} // Pass the index of the time slot
                />
              ) : (
                <p
                  style={{
                    height: "90px",
                    display: "flex",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                  }}
                  onDragOver={handleDragOver}
                  onDrop={handleDrop}
                  tabIndex={cellDate}
                ></p>
              )}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      );

      rows.push(row);

      day = addDays(day, 1);
    }

    return rows;
  };

  const handleNextWeek = () => {
    setSelectedDateState(addDays(selectedDate, 7));
  };
  const handlePreviousWeek = () => {
    setSelectedDateState(subDays(selectedDate, 7));
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: "20px",
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          marginBottom: "0px",
        }}
      >
        <h2 style={{ color: "#333333", margin: 0 }}>
          {format(startOfWeek(selectedDate), "MMMM d")} -{" "}
          {format(endOfWeek(selectedDate), "MMMM d, yyyy")}
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div className="calendar-container">
        <table className="calendar-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th> {/* Empty header cell for labels */}
              {[...Array(10)].map((_, index) => (
                <th key={index}>t{index + 1}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{generateCalendar()}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RunSheetPreview;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **handleDrop** function, you're currently calculating the new date based on the day retrieved from the **tabIndex** attribute of the drop target. Instead, you should use the day of the week provided by the calendar grid cell where the drop occurred. You can calculate the correct date by adding the **dayOfMonth** value (from the calendar grid cell) to the start date of the week.

Replace this line

```
const day = Number(number);
```

with this line

```
const day = dayOfMonth;
```

You need to implement functionality to save the modified **orderData** to a backend server or a local storage solution like **localStorage**. When the page loads, you should retrieve this saved data and initialize your state with it.
You can save **orderData** to **localStorage** whenever it changes:

```
localStorage.setItem('orderData', JSON.stringify(orderData));

useEffect(() => {
  const savedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orderData'));
  if (savedData) {
    setOrderData(savedData);
  }
}, []);
```

Ensure that changes made to the calendar persist even after a page reload, you should save the modified data to a persistent storage solution such as localStorage or a backend server.